# #snmplib error in snmpwalk command with agent

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpd, sharp-snmp

i try write a agent with sample code `snmpd` and define custom Object . but when i use `snmpwalk` in other library like `net-snmp` , my agent not return custom Object with value

> custom object

```
public TestObject(): base(new ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.4.1.52222"))
{
}
public override ISnmpData Data
{
    get
    {
        return new Integer32(12345);
    }
    set
    {
        throw new AccessFailureException();
    }
}
```

> my agent

```
var store = new ObjectStore();
store.Add(new SysDescr());
store.Add(new SysObjectId());
store.Add(new SysUpTime());
store.Add(new SysContact());
store.Add(new SysName());
store.Add(new SysLocation());
store.Add(new TestObject());
```

other code in my agent is like sample and not change 
result command line -> `snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 127.0.0.1`

```
SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: #SNMP Agent on Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID.0 = OID: SNMPv2-SMI::internet
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (17747798) 2 days, 1:17:57.98
SNMPv2-MIB::sysContact.0 = STRING: Taratech
SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = STRING: DESKTOP-T5PVHIB
SNMPv2-MIB::sysLocation.0 = STRING:
```

As you can see, the result is not correct and value of `TestObject` not return 
Where is my code wrong?

Comment: I don't think this has much to do with #SNMP yet, as our own `snmpwalk` command can query such custom objects. You have to refer to NET-SNMP reference to see how to use their command properly.